# Apostrophe issue when writing a string to SQL Server in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0, sql-server-2000, apostrophe

I am having issues writing this string to my SQL 200 database table:

**Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.**

How can I ensure that my vb.net app writes the above string exactly as it appears, to the field in the table ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using SqlCommand and SqlParameters, rather than raw SQL strings - for a variety of reasons. To escape characters in SQL, by default, I believe you simply need to double them up (eg. ' becomes '').

Comment: +1, Doubling the apostrophe is the right way to solve this problem, but it may not be the right problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only rules for escaping characters are:

1. Use two quotes for every one displayed
2. Escape wildcard characters (`_` and `%`) with a backslash

So you should easily be able to insert any string you like by first doing 3 search and replaces on your string - replacing `'` with `''`, replacing `_` with `\_`, and replacing `%` with `\%`